# Problem about normal subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$ and let $N$ be a normal subgroup of $G$.

Also:

$$HN=G$$
$$H\cap N={e}$$

Prove that $H$ is a representationsystem for the cosets $N$ in $G$ and $G/N≅H$.

I have no idea how to even begin with the first statement. With $G/N≅H$ I'm trying to prove that both sides are subsets of one another, but in either direction I have no idea how to begin.

Comment: For simple formula it is normally better to set them inline, that is using only one dollar symbol on each side, like `$H$`

Comment: Thanks! @quid, will remember :)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, note that

For all $x \in G$ there exists a unique couple $(h,n) \in H\times N$ such that $x = hn$.

In fact, if $hn=km$, for some $h,k \in H$, $n,m \in N$ then
$$k^{-1}h = mn^{-1} \in H\cap K = \{ e\}$$
so $h=k$ and $n=m$.

And now, you can define a group homomorphism $f:G \longrightarrow H$ as
$$f(hn) = h$$
Since the kernel of $f$ is $N$, you can conclude that $$G/N \cong f(G) = H$$

Finally, it is easy to see that every coset of the form $xN$ can be written in a unique way as $hnN = hN$ with $h \in H$. In fact, if $hN=kN$ ,then $hk^{-1} \in H \cap N$, so $h=k$.